# Fast Cross Entropy in Numpy

Tags: numpy, machine-learning

I have come up with two versions of Cross-Entropy one in the more vectorized dot product format and the other is the typical one you will see in any ML lecture. I am trying to speed my algorithm and thus will use any chance to speed it up.

[image]

```
  cost = -(1.0/m) * np.sum(Y*np.log(A) + (1-Y)*np.log(1-A))

    Vectorized Version
  cost = -(1.0/m) * (np.dot(np.log(A), Y.T) + np.dot(np.log(1-A), (1-Y).T))
```

My question: Which one of the above implementations of cross-entropy loss is computed fastest given the architecture of Numpy library and other constraints.

Comment: Just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

It would help with benchmarking to know typical values of labels. If labels are too short, a pure python implementation could actually be faster than using NumPy

Coming back to your question, I would say the dot products are already scalars (single numbers) the np.sum (which sums the array of products in the other style - [see](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html)) is not needed in "np dot style".

I hope it helps.